# Dynamically created Dropdown list does not return a value

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, dropdown

I create my dropdown based on values from an enum, then try to return the value by using the th:value="${parameterName}" like for other fields, but the return value is null.

Controller get method:

```
@GetMapping("/createorupdatebusvehicle/{id}")
public String createBusVehicleDisplay(Model model, @PathVariable(value = "id") long id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    BusVehicle busVehicle = busVehicleRepository.findById(id).get();
    if(busVehicle == null){
        response.sendRedirect("/createorupdatebusvehicle");
        return null;
    }

    model.addAttribute("busVehicleId", id);
   model.addAttribute("busVehicleColor", busVehicle.getColor().toString());
    model.addAttribute("busVehicleType", busVehicle.getType().toString());
// all attributes are set

    return "createOrUpdateBusVehicle";
}
```

Page view:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/createorupdatebusvehicle}" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="busVehicleId" th:value="${busVehicleId}" />
<p>Plate number: <input type="text" name="busVehiclePlateNumber" th:value="${busVehiclePlateNumber}" /></p>
<p>Passenger capacity: <input type="text" name="busVehiclePassengerCapacity" th:value="${busVehiclePassengerCapacity}" /></p>

//== Here are the selects ==

<select name="color">
    <option th:each="colorOpt : ${T(com.grazzini.model.BusVehicleColor).values()}"
            th:value="${busVehicleColor}" th:text="${colorOpt}" th:selected="${busVehicleColor} == colorOpt"></option>
</select>

<select name="type">
    <option th:each="typeOpt : ${T(com.grazzini.model.BusVehicleType).values()}"
            th:value="${busVehicleType}" th:text="${typeOpt}" th:selected="${busVehicleType} == typeOpt"></option>
</select>
```

Then get the selected value back in the controller:

```
@PostMapping("/createorupdatebusvehicle")
public String checkAndCreateBusVehicle (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String busVehicleId = request.getParameter("busVehicleId");
//...
    String busVehicleColor = request.getParameter("busVehicleColor"); //null
    String busVehicleType = request.getParameter("busVehicleType"); //null

/// the rest
```

Color and Type are enums. All other requests return the correct value, for a text field for example. Any idea why this one behave differently?

Answer (score 0):

You have `name="..."` on the fields that are working.  You need to add `name="busVehicleColor"` and `name="busVehicleType"` on your respective `<select />` tags..